# Find the $x$-value at which $f$ is discontinuous: Graph

Tags: calculus

Find the $x$-value at which $f$ is discontinuous and determine whether $f$ is continuous from the right, or from the left, or neither.

How is the graph in right upper-hand corner continuous in the left but not the right?

I thought a graph could be continuous between intervals no matter if there was a hole at the end of it

Can someone explain this?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a function $f$ is continuous from:

- the left at a number $a$ if $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a^-}f(x)=f(a);$
- the right at a number $a$ if $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a^+}f(x)=f(a).$

Applying this definition, we have $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x) \neq f(0)$, since $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x)=3$ and $f(0)=1$ but $3\neq 1$. Thus, $f$ is is not continuous from the right of $0$.

Even if there is a hole, you can evaluate the limit from the left or the right side. But with continuity, we must also have the limit of $x$ as it tends to $a$ equal the value of the function at $a$. You might be confusing these two.